# How to enable etnaviv drivers without using Yocto build?

Tags: qt, linux-kernel, mesa

I have custom board with kernel 4.14 and vivante drivers 6.2.4p4.0 (Official Freescale's ones).
I want to test my Qt application using the mesa drivers instead of the Freescale's.
I've already downloaded and manually compiled and installed the mesa drivers with *kmsro* and *etnaviv* drivers options enabled, but these steps doesn't seem to be enough.

What are the steps to do after installing the mesa drivers to enable them?

I don't have access to a Yocto layer for my board, so rebuilding the image is not an option.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the etnaviv kernel module enabled, I did the following:

Download and compile kernel source v4.14, enabling the following options:

- Device Drivers-> Graphics Support-> `[M]ETNAVIV`
- MXC support drivers-> MXC Vivante GPU support->`[*]MXC Vivante GPU support`

Then install or compile MESA. If you choose to compile MESA remember to enable the options `kmsro` and `etnaviv` on the meson_options.txt file.

Lastly, to check if etnaviv was successfully loaded, do:

```
# dmesg | grep etnaviv
```

Should output something like this:

```
[    6.249793] etnaviv gpu-subsystem: bound 134000.gpu (ops gpu_ops [etnaviv])
[    6.249866] etnaviv gpu-subsystem: bound 130000.gpu (ops gpu_ops [etnaviv])
[    6.249919] etnaviv gpu-subsystem: bound 2204000.gpu (ops gpu_ops [etnaviv])
[    6.249934] etnaviv-gpu 134000.gpu: model: GC320, revision: 5007
[    6.332274] etnaviv-gpu 130000.gpu: model: GC2000, revision: 5108
[    6.402442] etnaviv-gpu 2204000.gpu: model: GC355, revision: 1215
[    6.402474] etnaviv-gpu 2204000.gpu: Ignoring GPU with VG and FE2.0
[    6.416880] [drm] Initialized etnaviv 1.1.0 20151214 for gpu-subsystem on minor 1
```

Check also your dtb file for proper initialization, mine has the following entries regarding the gpu:

```
        gpu@00130000 {
            compatible = "vivante,gc";
            reg = <0x130000 0x4000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0x9 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x2 0x1b 0x2 0x7a 0x2 0x4a>;
            clock-names = "bus", "core", "shader";
            power-domains = <0x9>;
            linux,phandle = <0x82>;
            phandle = <0x82>;
    };

    gpu@00134000 {
            compatible = "vivante,gc";
            reg = <0x134000 0x4000>;
            interrupts = <0x0 0xa 0x4>;
            clocks = <0x2 0x1a 0x2 0x79>;
            clock-names = "bus", "core";
            power-domains = <0x9>;
            linux,phandle = <0x81>;
            phandle = <0x81>;
    };

    gpu@02204000 {
        compatible = "vivante,gc";
        reg = <0x2204000 0x4000>;
        interrupts = <0x0 0xb 0x4>;
        clocks = <0x2 0x8f 0x2 0x79>;
        clock-names = "bus", "core";
        power-domains = <0x9>;
        linux,phandle = <0x83>;
        phandle = <0x83>;
    };

   gpu-subsystem {
        compatible = "fsl,imx-gpu-subsystem";
        cores = <0x81 0x82 0x83>;
    };
```

Note: If you get a dmesg error output like "*command buffer outside valid memory window*", it might be the case that you need to increase the cma being reserved. You must do it via kernel parameter, In my case I had to set via uboot the following: `cma=256M@2G`